# Observe com.apple.configuration.managed only, and not all Defaults?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to observe any changes to the "com.apple.configuration.managed" plist on iOS.

To do that, I now do this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(........), name: UserDefaults.didChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

this works and I get notified when any defaults changes. So then when I get that notification I filter for the "com.apple.configuration.managed" key on the notification object and then react as needed.

Is there a way to **only observe changes to the "com.apple.configuration.managed" plist** and not the entire App Defaults?

Comment: Try `object: UserDefaults(suiteName: "com.apple.configuration.manager")` instead of `object: nil`.

Comment: @robmayoff that does not work. I never get the notification when using `object: UserDefaults(suiteName: "com.apple.configuration.manager")`.